# How to get two variables to always equal a constant ratio?

Tags: javascript

I have two variables: `width` and `height`. Assume that the variables are two random positive numbers.

`Width` and `height` must always equal the ratio of 1.4:1.

To put it another way,

`width / height === 1.4`

Must always evaluate to `true`.

In JavaScript, how do I change width and height so that they always equal this constant ratio?

Comment: How can they be random AND be sure to have a fix ratio?

Comment: They are populated with random numbers at first. Then, they have to be changed to equal the ratio.

Comment: you can encapsulate them in an object and then impose the restriction

Comment: @InspectorDanno after they are assigned random numbers, reassign `width = 1.4 * height`, but don't change the value of `height`

Comment: The variables are not independent. So just make one random choice and multiply by 1.4.

Comment: If you are allowed to alter either of their value, it should be sufficient to decide that, say, `width` will be changed to `1.4 * height`.

Comment: @InspectorDanno - if they have to be changed to equal the ratio, that means one stays the same while the other changes. So which random value do you want to stay the same, width or height?

Comment: I'd suggest using [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

Comment: If `width / height == 1.4` then `width = 1.4 * height` and `height = width / 1.4`

Answer (score 4):

```
  const obj = {
    width: 100 * Math.random(),
    get height() { return this.width / 1.4; },
    set height(v) { this.width = v * 1.4; },
 };
```

Use getters and setters to change them both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting two random numbers and need to change them to equal the ratio, you'll need to pick one and define the other based on it. For instance:

```
width = height * 1.4;
```